# Winforms and the MVP Design Pattern?

Tags: c#, winforms, mvp

Alright, so I've read up a bit on the MVP design pattern, but I'm still somewhat confused.

I assume it's as follows:

- Model = Data Entities (such as a class that represents a person).
- View = The designer generated code of the form.
- Presentation = The non-designer code of the form. Basically just
  handles events from the view and based on those events, it affects
  the view and the model.

However, I have a feeling that this is wrong. If it is, I'm wondering if anyone could explain why?